# OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread using ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I launched my instance overnight to see how it handled things and when I came by this morning, I was facing a

```
Exception in thread "pool-535-thread-7" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:691)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:943)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processWorkerExit(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:992)[info] application - Connecting to server A
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

The aim of my code is quite simple : Every 5 minutes, I connect to a list of remote server, send a request (via socket) and that's it.

Here's my code :

My "cron" task :

```
/** will create a new instance of ExecutorService every 5 minutes, loading all the websites in the database to check their status **/
/** Maybe that's where the problem is ? I need to empty (GC ?) this ExecutorService ? **/
Akka.system().scheduler().schedule(
    Duration.create(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), // Initial delay 0 milliseconds
    Duration.create(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES),     // Frequency 5 minutes
    new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // We get the list of websites to check
            Query<Website> query = Ebean.createQuery(Website.class, "WHERE disabled = false AND removed IS NULL");
            query.order("created ASC");
            List<Website> websites = query.findList(); // Can be 1, 10, 100, 1000. In my test case, I had only 9 websites.

            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NTHREDS);
            for (Website website : websites) {
                CheckWebsite task = new CheckWebsite(website);
                executor.execute(task);
            }

            // This will make the executor accept no new threads
            // and finish all existing threads in the queue
            executor.shutdown();
        }
    },
    Akka.system().dispatcher()
);
```

My CheckWebsite class :

```
public class CheckWebsite implements Runnable {
    private Website website;

    public CheckWebsite(Website website) {
        this.website = website;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        WebsiteLog log = website.checkState(); // This is where the request is made, I copy paste the code just after
        if (log == null) {
            Logger.error("OHOH, WebsiteLog should not be null for website.checkState() in CheckWebsite class :s");
            return;
        }

        try {
            log.save();
       catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.info ("An error occured :/");
            Logger.info(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My `checkState()` method in `Website.class` :

```
public WebsiteLog checkState() {
    // Since I use Socket and the connection can hang indefinitely, I use an other ExecutorService in order to limit the time spent
    // The duration is defined via Connector.timeout, Which will be the next code.

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

    Connector connector = new Connector(this);
    try {
        final long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        Future<String> future = executor.submit(connector);
        String response = future.get(Connector.timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        long duration = System.nanoTime() - startTime;

        return PlatformLog.getLastOccurence(this, response, ((int) duration/ 1000000));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return PlatformLog.getLastOccurence(this, null, null);
    }
}
```

Here's the `Connector.class`. I removed useless part here (like Catches) :

```
public class Connector implements Callable<String> {
    public final static int timeout = 2500; // WE use a timeout of 2.5s, which should be enough

    private Website website;

    public Connector(Website website) {
        this.website = website;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        Logger.info ("Connecting to " + website.getAddress() + ":" + website.getPort());
        Socket socket = new Socket();

        try {
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(website.getIp(), website.getPort()), (timeout - 50));
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String response = input.readLine();
            socket.close();

            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
        finally {
            // I take the precaution to close the socket here in order to avoid a memory leak
            // But if the previous ExecutorService force the close of this thread before
            // I can't guarantee it will be closed :/
            if (socket != null && !socket.isClosed()) {
                socket.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm new to Java multithreading so I probably made big mistake. I suspect some area that could be potentially the reason, but my lack of knowledge requires me to ask for your help :)

As a summary, here's the potentials areas :

1. Creating a new `ExecutorService` every 5 minutes. Maybe I can reuse the old one ? Or do I need to close the current one when finished (if so, how ?).
2. The fact that I create an `ExecutorService` that will create an `ExecutorService` (in the `checkstate()` method)
3. The fact that the Connector class can be (violently) stopped by the `ExecutorService` running it, if it takes too long, resulting in a socket not closed (and then a memory leak) ?

Also, as you can see, the exception occured for the thread "pool-535-thread-7" which mean it didn't happen soon.

I store the last_occured check in the database, and the creation of the log entry (in `WebsiteLog`), the delta is around 5 hours (so, for every 5 minutes, the thread crashed after around 60 calls).

**Update** : Here's the revisited checkState method to include the shutdown call :

```
public PlatformLog checkState() {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

    Connector connector = new Connector(this);
    String response = null;
    Long duration = null;

    try {
        final long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        Future<String> future = executor.submit(connector);
        response = future.get(Connector.timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        duration = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}

    executor.shutdown();
    if (duration != null) {
        return WebsiteLog.getLastOccurence(this, response, (duration.intValue()/ 1000000));
    }
    else {
        return WebsiteLog.getLastOccurence(this, response, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you think you've found a fix, why not test it? Change your cron job to every 1 minute (or less?) and you can reach 60 calls in an hour...

Comment: That's clever ! :p I'll do that. - See you in 30 mins ;) (every 30s)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the only problem, but you are creating an `ExecutorService` in your `checkState()` method but you don't shut it down.

According to the JavaDocs for [`Executors.newFixedThreadPool()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29):

> The threads in the pool will exist **until it is explicitly shutdown.**

The threads staying alive will cause the `ExecutorService` [not to be garbage collected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7728645/474189) (which would call `shutdown()` on your behalf. Hence you are leaking a thread each time this is called.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to shutdown the ExecutorService, thank you for that. But regarding the Connector, how do I exit it ? I do a return in the try, but nothing in the catch/finally. Should I do something here too ?

Comment: @CyrilN. No, it looks fine to me. You either return a result or you throw an exception, which is the correct behaviour. It wouldn't compile if it wasn't!

Comment: I updated my question to show the revisited version of `checkState()`. Do you think it's better like this? By the way, If I throw back the exception in `Connector.class`, I will never go to the finally block right (so I will never close the socket) ?

Comment: @CyrilN. Also note that an `ExecutorService` doesn't force threads to stop. It may try and interrupt the thread, but your code doesn't look for interrupt status. So, at worst, your blocking socket calls will be interrupted, which will be caught by your exception code. Your `finally` clause will still run.

Comment: @CyrilN. The only thing that can stop a `finally` clause being executed is a forcible termination of the JVM. In *every other case*, the `finally` block will execute, including if you throw an exception.

Comment: Well, I made the modification you said, I also removed the finally by setting socket as a class variable, and a public methode `closeSocket()` which is called in the `catch()` block of `checkState()`. I restarted the instance. I'll tell you how things goes. Thank you a lot for your help !

Comment: Well, still no sign of errors, so I think it's the solution! I accepted it ! Thank you again :)