# Why doesn't all `Executors` factory methods wrap in a `FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService`?

Tags: java, concurrency

[`Executors#newSingleThreadExecutor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()) returns a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) wrapped in `FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService` (not public). `FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService` makes sure that the thread pool is shut down when garbage collected.

Why aren't all `ExecutorService`s returned by `Executors` wrapped in something like `FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService`? Does a `ThreadPoolExecutor` shut down properly without being wrapped in a `FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService` if garbage collected?

Comment: If not shut down, it still holds references to its internal threads which would prevent it from being garbage collected.

Comment: Hm, interesting. But will it ever be garbage collected since a running thread might refer back to the executor? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10395700/260805.

Comment: the threads have no knowledge of the wrapper, only of the wrapped executor

Comment: you may be interested in this   https://www.farside.org.uk/201309/learning_from_bad_code

Comment: Adam: Great reference! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't be relying on finalization in the first place. So one could even argue that none of them should be wrapped.

Anyway, not all pools created by the `Executors` factory methods are the same. Some of a core pool size of zero, so there are no threads to clean up.

Similarly forkjoinpool cleans up idle threads after 2 seconds and becomes GCable once there are no threads to keep it alive, so there's no need for explicit finalization.